# Codeigniter -> function using empty_table

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am trying to empty the tables but I was wondering have I got the function correct?

**Model:**

```
public function removeQuote()
    {
        $this->db->empty_table('companyDetails,hostingDetails,layoutDetails');
    }
```

**Controller:**

```
public function submit()
{
        $data['companyContact'] = $this->quote->getCompanyDetails()->companyContact;

        $this->load->view('submit',$data);

        $this->quote->removeQuote();
}
```

**Error:**

```
Table '_quote.companyDetails,hostingDetails,layoutDetails' doesn't exist

DELETE FROM `companyDetails,hostingDetails,layoutDetails`
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
/**
 * Empty Table
 *
 * Compiles a delete string and runs "DELETE FROM table"
 *
 * @param   string  the table to empty
 * @return  object
 */
public function empty_table($table = '')
```

Apparently you can't do this

```
$this->db->empty_table('companyDetails,hostingDetails,layoutDetails');
```

Instead you will have to call `empty_table` three times:

```
$this->db->empty_table('companyDetails');
$this->db->empty_table('hostingDetails');
$this->db->empty_table('layoutDetails');
```

You can always hack CodeIgniter DB_active_rec.php file so that it fits your needs.

Comment: What if I don't want to delete the auto increment value?

Answer (score 0):

In your controller you have to load the model first (if it's not auto loaded)

```
$this->load->model('quote'); // Assuming your model name is 'quote'
```

before you use the function from that model as you used in your controller as follows

```
$data['companyContact'] = $this->quote->getCompanyDetails()->companyContact;
```

and load the view at last, after all code has been executed even after following line

```
$this->quote->removeQuote();
```

Just checked in `CI` doc `empty_table` doesn't accept multiple table names.

Comment: maybe he first loaded it in his `__construct ()`, is there really a method called `empty_tables ()` in the Database class of CodeIgniter?

Comment: I have got my model auto loaded and please see here: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html#delete

Comment: Ok, didn't know about that! but please show us your error log

Comment: Does empty_table accepts multiple table names, i didn't see it in the doc ?

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION ONE**

```
$this->db->truncate('companyDetails');
$this->db->truncate('hostingDetails');
$this->db->truncate('layoutDetails');
```

**SOLUTION TWO**

```
 function emptytablesbycomma($stringoftables) {
            $array_tablenames = explode(",", $stringoftables);
            if (!empty($array_tablenames)) {
                foreach ($array_tablenames as $tablename) {
                    $this->db->truncate($tablename);
                }
            }
        }
```

> Usage

```
$stringoftables='companyDetails,hostingDetails,layoutDetails';
$this->emptytablesbycomma($stringoftables);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$tablelist = array("companyDetails,hostingDetails,layoutDetails");
        foreach ($tablelist as $able) {
            $this->db->truncate($able);
        }
```